# Unable to post a question because tags won't display in drop down menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ask-question-wizard-2018

[image: Browser Console][image: No Drop-down Menu]I'm currently trying to post a question but when I enter a tag like python, no drop-down menu appears, and so the post question button remains greyed out.

Comment: Related: [Can't post a new question using guided mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386581/4642212).

Comment: When you open the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), do you see some JavaScript errors or some warnings that certain scripts failed to load?

Comment: It [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAAUY.jpg) on Firefox Nightly 69.0a1.

Comment: No errors in browser console, and not working in Firefox nightly. May be an issue with my computer if that's the case?

Comment: Win 10 Chrome 75, console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initEditor' of undefined`

Comment: @SamuelLiew here is a similar report for that initEditor problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386395/not-seeing-formatting-toolbar-on-ask-question-screen I wonder if that dupe there is correct. And here is that same error mentioned https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380541/578411 which indicates this is a network timing / async issue. Those are hard to diagnose for devs. I think it is fair to raise the issue with a CM as no SE Dev seem to have noticed so far.

Comment: Linking to more evidence / occurrences: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330126/158100

Comment: Dev here. As @rene mentioned, looks like this might have been happening for [some time with the same error popping up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386395/not-seeing-formatting-toolbar-on-ask-question-screen). It seems like it's only affecting some users sometimes (it's working ok here and confirmed with another dev). This requires some deeper investigation. I'll dig into this and report back.

Comment: @JonChan Edited picture to add something I found in the browser console. Not sure if it is relevant or not.

Comment: @MaxwellGyimah In the meantime, you can also get to [traditional mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false) and try posting your question there. Most if not all of your question content should be saved and hopefully you won't run into the same issue so you can post.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue not loading all the scripts.  Pressing Shift+F5 should resolve.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you have any extensions like NoScript that might be blocking something?

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome OS 74.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm using Google Chrome. No extensions like that.

Comment: @MaxwellGyimah Thanks. That info goes in the question. ;) Actually, any extensions are worth noting.

Comment: Other than the five linked questions in the sidebar, these were also deleted: [386692](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386692), [386696](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386696), [386602](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386602), [386731](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386731)

Comment: Update (just to let you know that we are working on it): I can reproduce it on prod by refreshing the page a few times (doesn't happen every time, maybe every 3 or 4 refreshes). Doing a hard refresh always makes it go away. Have been unable to replicate on my local yet. Still digging.

Comment: [Here's another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386731/6296561) (deleted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just pushed code that should fix this. Ask away! (And if you see any instances where it is still not working, please leave a comment on this answer).

Comment: I assume that will be deployed in a revision higher then: 2019.7.1.34180 ?

Comment: @rene it was deployed over three hours ago

Comment: I've just run into this issue when asking a question using guided mode using Internet explorer 11 version 11.885.17134.0